# One row exists even though there are no results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT info.pID, Name, Addr, Phone, GROUP_CONCAT(URL) as URL FROM info, images WHERE info.pID = images.pID AND place='$place';
```

Even though there are no results found, one row is created (as stated by num_rows and js .length), any ideas why? It is not an usual thing to happen.

**JSON result print:**

```
[{"0":null,"pID":null,"1":null,"Name":null,"2":null,"Addr":null,"3":null,"Phone":null,"4":null,"URL":null}]
```

Comment: So show us the code, and we'll show you how none can become one

Comment: Where's the code that creates the JSON?

Comment: You need to show some PHP code the generates that JSON from that SQL.

Comment: if `$place` is user input, you have security hole.

Comment: Why are you using an *aggregate* function "GROUP_CONCAT" in a query that does not have a "GROUP BY" clause? I am not sure, but maybe that creates the extra row. Try removing that one item from results and check whether there is still one row created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of `GROUP_CONCAT`: all aggregating functions have a similar behaviour, the query is executed and the concat is performed when building the result-set. If there are no results it concatenates NULL, and is added to an otherwise empty result-set. If one field holds a value (in this case the NULL returned by a function), all other fields are displayed, too (obviously).

That explains the 1 row result, where everything is null. Remove the group_concat, and you won't get any results back. Just think of how that other aggregating function `COUNT()` would behave in the same situation. 
[Here's a list of all aggregating functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: What do you suggest as an alternative for checking if there are results?

Comment: That all depends on what you need, if you need the `GROUP_CONCAT`, you can add a `COUNT()`, too and check the value of that field. Some might even suggest querying twice (I wouldn't, though). Perhaps a stored procedure might work for you, but in general, I tend to avoid aggregate functions, because of this behaviour

Comment: I need group_concat to prevent duplicate rows, since there is possiblity of mulitple rows joining one unique row.

Comment: @JamaicaBob: just at the end of your query: ` GROUP_CONCAT(URL) as URL,COUNT(URL) as resultNum FROM...`, then, when you fetch the first row, just check `$row['resultNum'] == 0`, if it is, you're dealing with an empty result set. Just a tip: it's always better to count a specific field (preferably one with an index on it, too) instead of `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Only one more question: Is querying done twice if i also add COUNT() to the existing query?  (select query + count query) or does it just count the previously selected items?

Comment: @JamaicaBob: one query. It took me a while to figure out how MySQL works, but it's good to know: First, your query is executed: the table indexes are opened (like you'd create a file pointer in php), and then the WHERE clause (and JOINS) are used to get a list of rows that match the search criteria. Only then MySQL turns its attention to the fields you want selected: it's only got a hold of the indexes and the location of their respective records. Then it compiles the result set. Any functions in your SELECT are then executed (no new query). I suggested COUNT-ing an index field

Comment: Since MySQL has access to these fields before a non-indexed data field. to get those, MySQL _has_ to get through the indexes, and _then_ look for the field you need counted, which might be all over the hard-disk. This, as you probably know, is less then ideal

Comment: @JamaicaBob: NP, glad I could help... shame I can't cache in on those million thanks, by means of a million up-votes ;-)

Comment: Hehe yea, that would be great. :))

Answer (score 0):

There might be other columns with data in the row that is specified with your `place='$place'`

The part after `SELECT` before `FROM` only filters the results you got from the rest of the query. So if `FROM info, images WHERE info.pID = images.pID AND place='$place';` finds something you have a result. You then filter the result and select only specific columns which could be empty, hence your result.